# Show yaxis out the plot in highstock

Tags: highcharts

I would like that both yAxis and their labels in charts located at http://contenidopremium.estrategiasdeinversion.com/modulos/indicadores/framework_indicadores.php?t=BBVA&k=msdgv8IUDfviuqweRH9snsdvu7wsaeuvc87awer43sdney where displayed out the plot (not overflow in chart) as you can see in this chart http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols but I don't find the difference or the correct options. I think that the difference is that demo is highchart and mine is highstock but I'm not sure.

Could anybody help me?

Thank ins advance, txetxu.

Comment: Can you post your chart definition code ? It's likely to be something to do with the 'legend' options you are using.

Comment: I tried it and with Highchart the yAxis show out the plot, can I get the same with Highstock?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/PZzYR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`yAxis.labels.align`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.align) to right, and manipulate x/y values, see: http://jsfiddle.net/JJLBp/

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the position of the legend using the 'align' and 'verticalAlign' options. Try something like this:

```
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
},
```

This works with highstock http://jsfiddle.net/PZzYR/.

Comment: Thank you @SteveP but the problem it's not with legend. It's with yAxis, you can see the difference between Highchart and HighStock in this [image](http://contenidopremium.estrategiasdeinversion.com/modulos/indicadores/images/stackoverflow_in_out_yaxis.png)